# Prove inequality e^x > x^(n+1)/(n+1)!

Tags: analysis

How can I prove this inequality?

$e^x > \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1!}$

I thought of solving it by using:

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e < (1-\frac{1}{n})^{-n}$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: $e^x=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: In what context is this problem? How is $e^x$ defined for your purposes? (In particular, do you have a power series for it?)

Comment: @prets I have to prove that e^(-1/x) = o(x^n) for x -> 0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Taylor series of the exponential, whose radius of convergence is infinite.

$$e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$

Can you proceed?

Observe that due to the previous series, we can write the partial sum for $k$ from $0$ to $n+2$:

$$1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots + \dfrac{x^n}{n!} + \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + \dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!} + \ldots$$

And this, being a sum of positive terms, is surely greater than $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Why is it a sum of positive terms? What if $x<0$?

Comment: @markvs Then we can give an estimation with enough terms, and an opportune remainder and we can show the partial sum will still be positive, since it's the series of the exponential.

Comment: Who are "we" and what is "your" estimation?

Comment: That's not part of the question, and I think you are able enough to prove it yourself.

Comment: In the question, $x$ is arbitrary, can be negative. In fact in the comment the OP writes that the interesting case is $e^{-1/x}$, so the exponent can be negative.

Comment: @markvs You can use a series of strictly positive terms:
$$\exp(-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\exp(-x-n\log2)}$$

Indeed suppose that $\exp(-x)=\sum f_n(x)$, where each $f_n$ is a strictly positive function. Then $f_n$ can't be a polynomial, since polynomials blow up as $x\to\infty$, whereas $0<f_n(x)<\exp(-x)$. 

Or you can use Padé approximants.

Comment: Notice that I said "the exponential cannot be negative", not "the exponent".

Comment: I do not understand it. Why is this equality true? Why $\sqrt{2}$? And what does it have to do with the question? Perhaps if you correct your answer, it will be clearer. Yes, $\exp(x)$ is positive for every $x$ and it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$e^x > \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1!}$$
can be proven by
$$ e^x = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac {x^l}{l!} \ge \sum_{l=n+1}^\infty \frac {x^l}{l!} \ge \frac {x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $$

Comment: Your first $\ge$ is not clear.